# Existence of two-color paths between boundary vertices in a near-triangulated plane graph with an external face of degree 4

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Let G be a plane graph with the following characteristics:

$1.$ It is near-triangulated.

$2.$ It has an external face of degree $4$ (i.e. the graph has $4$ boundary vertices, a diamond-shaped boundary ring).

$3.$ It has no separating triangle (a triangle with vertices of G both inside and outside the triangle).

$4.$ None of its four boundary vertices has degree $< 4.$

$5.$ It has no internal path of length two between a pair of opposite boundary vertices.

Let the boundary cycle of G be denoted uxvy, thus establishing (u,v) and (x,y) as the two pairs of opposite boundary vertices.

Can you find a G, other than the one depicted below, for which either (a) or (b) is true?

$(a)$ No $4-$coloring of G has a $2-$color path between x and y using colors different from the color(s) of u and v.

$(b)$ No $4-$coloring of G has a $2-$color path between u and v using colors different from the color(s) of x and y.

[image: embedded birkhoff diamond]